# Fetching and displaying groups from database as menu links

Tags: php, mysql

First I want to say that I'm not sure that this is the proper way doing this so if there is better way please tell me.

I have input form with few dropdown and checkboxes on it. I want admin to have access to them via backend and to be able to edit/delete/create new.

I have made table in database `form_field` with `field_id`, `field_name` and `group_id`. `group_id` is where I store for which dropdown menu are this fields. For example dropdown Category with select options: `Category_1`, `Category_2`...`Category_n`. In database table will be:

```
field_id    field_name    group_id
   1        Category_1       1
   2        Category_2       1
   3        Category_n       1
```

Next dropdown on the page will be group_id=2..
Now I want to put them on the admin page like:

```
Manage "Category"
Manage "Some other dropdown group"
etc
```

How to loop the table so the name `Manage "Category"` to be link and take `group_id=1`, next will be `Manage "Some other dropdown group"` `group_id=2` ... etc. Here is what I thought it will be but it is showing me only the first group because this is the condition..

```
    $sql = $pdo->prepare("SELECT * FROM form_fields");  
    $sql->execute(); 
    $row = $sql->fetch();                       

    if($row['group_id'] == 1){
            echo '<li><a href="drops.php?group_id='.$row['group_id'].'"><i class="fa fa-angle-double-right"></i> Manage "Category_1"</a></li>';
    } elseif($row['group_id'] == 2) {
            echo '<li><a href="drops.php?group_id='.$row['group_id'].'"><i class="fa fa-angle-double-right"></i> Manage "Category_2"</a></li>';
    } elseif($row['group_id'] == 3) {
            echo '<li><a href="drops.php?group_id='.$row['group_id'].'"><i class="fa fa-angle-double-right"></i> Manage "Category_3"</a></li>';
    } elseif($row['group_id'] == 4) {
            echo '<li><a href="drops.php?group_id='.$row['group_id'].'"><i class="fa fa-angle-double-right"></i> Manage "Category_4"</a></li>';
    }
```

Looks something simple but I'm stuck with this..

Comment: Your fetch option is missing one parameter which is

`$sql->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)`

Try this I think this might help you out

Comment: @AhmedKhan .. no no .. here the problem is that it's showing me only first group_id.. i.e. because first condition is true and didn't check others..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are selecting all from the table so you will be getting back multiple rows. For that you will need to loop through the rows like so:

```
<?php

$sql = $pdo->prepare("SELECT * FROM form_fields");  
$sql->execute();
$rows = $sql->fetch();

$html = [];
foreach ($rows as $row) {
    $html []= '<li><a href="drops.php?group_id='.$row['group_id'].'"><i class="fa fa-angle-double-right"></i> Manage "' . $row['field_name'] . '"</a></li>';
}
echo join("", $html);

?>
```

Hope this is sort of what you are looking for.

Comment: Thank's but I got this errors: `PHP Warning:  Illegal string offset 'group_id'`, `PHP Warning:  Illegal string offset 'field_name'`, `PHP Fatal error:  Function name must be a string`

Comment: comment out the string concatenation for now and print_r($row); from within the loop, what do you get?

Comment: sorry but `string contamination` which one is this?

Comment: sorry it was auto correct: concatenation. its the $html [] = line

`foreach ($rows as $row) {
    //$html []= '<li><a href="drops.php?group_id='.$row['group_id'].'"><i class="fa fa-angle-double-right"></i> Manage "' . $row['field_name'] . '"</a></li>';
print_r($row);
}`

Comment: `PHP Fatal error:  Function name must be a string in`

Comment: also make your fetch method look like this: `$sql->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);`

Comment: Yes, still this error `PHP Fatal error:  Function name must be a string` when I `print_r($row)`

Comment: What are `$html = [];` and `echo $join("", $html);` ? the error for `function name must be a string` is on this line `echo $join...`

Comment: `print_r($rows)` outside `foreach` is showing proper result.. So the problem is with this array html..

Comment: I am such a nob!!!!! $join("", $html); needs to be join("", $html);, remove the "$" sign from join. Sorry about that...

Comment: Now there is no errors but it doesn't show correctly. It is showing only 2 results -> `1` which is first row from the table + first letter of the word..

Comment: This happen when I fetch them like this: `$rows = $sql->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);` if I fetch them with `$rows = $sql->fetchAll();` I got every row from table which is also not how they must come..

Comment: I don't know if you understand me.. generally it is showing only firs row from the table. Only first record i.e. 1,E,1 which is equalent of `field_id = 1`, `field_name = economic` and showing only first letter E, `group_id=1`

Comment: Well your code works fine. The problem is in my database design. Thank's for the help I will try to fix my other issue.